# Process html files with HttpModule to catch 404 errors on IIS7

Tags: c#, iis-7, httpmodule

I am having another problem with my HttpModule that handles exceptions. (cfr. my previous post: [Custom HttpModule for IIS 7 for integrated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5911923/custom-httpmodule-for-iis-7-for-integrated))

All works well, but only for aspx pages.

*The main reason we wanted to use this HttpModule is to handle 404 exceptions that occur when someone tries to go to a html page that doesn't exist. But my HttpModule only works for .aspx pages and it isn't triggered when a html file doesn't exist.*

This is the configuration that I have set up in my web.conf file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <add name="AspExceptionHandler" 
         type="Company.Exceptions.AspExceptionHandler, Company.Exceptions" 
         preCondition="managedHandler" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

I have also tried adding 'runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"' to the module node, and 'preCondition="managedHandler"' to the "add" node, but this also didn't work.

I have set the Application pool on which my web application is running to "Integrated" mode, because I found this a lot on google.

**Is there another way to make my HttpModule handle exceptions that occur when visiting a non existing *html* page?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done a little research based on the answer of Alexander, I implemented IHttpHandler in my AspExceptionHandler as well.

My class now looks like:

```
public class AspExceptionHandler : IHttpModule, IHttpHandler
    {
        public void Dispose() { }

        public void Init(HttpApplication context)
        {
            context.Error += new EventHandler(ErrorHandler);
        }

        private void ErrorHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication application = (HttpApplication)sender;
            try
            {
                // Gather information
                Exception currentException = application.Server.GetLastError(); ;
                String errorPage = "http://companywebsite.be/error.aspx";

                HttpException httpException = currentException as HttpException;
                if (httpException == null || httpException.GetHttpCode() != 404)
                {
                    application.Server.Transfer(errorPage, true);
                }
                //The error is a 404
                else
                {
                    // Continue
                    application.Server.ClearError();

                    String shouldMail404 = true;

                    //Try and redirect to the proper page.
                    String requestedFile = application.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Trim('/').Split('/').Last();

                    // Redirect if required
                    String redirectURL = getRedirectURL(requestedFile.Trim('/'));
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(redirectURL))
                    {
                        //Redirect to the proper URL
                    }
                    //If we can't redirect properly, we set the statusCode to 404.
                    else
                    {
                        //Report the 404
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ExceptionCatcher.FillWebException(HttpContext.Current, ref ex);
                ExceptionCatcher.CatchException(ex);
            }
        }

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            if (!File.Exists(context.Request.PhysicalPath)) 
            {
                throw new HttpException(404, String.Format("The file {0} does not exist", context.Request.PhysicalPath));
            }
                    else
            {
                context.Response.TransmitFile(context.Request.PhysicalPath);
            }
        }
    }
```

In the ProcessRequest method (required by the IHttpHandler) I check if the file exists.
If it does not exist, I throw an HttpException that is catched by the HttpModule part of my class.

The system.webServer node in my web.config now looks like this:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
            <add name="AspExceptionHandler" type="Company.Exceptions.AspExceptionHandler, Company.Exceptions" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        </modules>
        <handlers>
            <add name="AspExceptionHandler" type="Company.Exceptions.AspExceptionHandler, Company.Exceptions" verb="*" path="*.html" />
        </handlers>
```

I found the answer in in this post: [HttpHandler fire only if file doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269370/httphandler-fire-only-if-file-doesnt-exist)

Comment: +1 for giving credit where due.  It's mostly correct but a little silly.  Why are you making a class that's a module and a handler?  You're only really using the handler aspect.  Also, if you want to register it for "*" (anything that falls through the cracks) it oversteps its bounds and stops the other handlers from working. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
<httpHandlers>
    <add type="Company.Exceptions.AspExceptionHandler, Company.Exceptions" verb="*" path="*"/> 
    ....
</httpHandlers>
```

this help you to catch all request, but if reqest is made for existing page you need to pass it to standart handler

Comment: Doesn't the AspExceptionHandler has to be an IHttpHandler to be added as a handler? Well, I have tested it and I get the error the AspExceptionHandler does not implement the IHttpHandler, or is that what you are saying, that I should convert my class to an HttpHandler in order for it to process all requests?

Comment: sorry, i had thought that your class is IHttpHandler because of the it's name :) anyway, i hope this answer show you the way to do this

Comment: Ow, yes, I took AspExceptionHandler because it handles exceptions :). Your post was really helpful as you can see in my answer below :)... Thanks very much for your help!